# Testing Ember with Mocha - visit() causes tests to abort

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, phantomjs, mocha.js

When running `visit()`, the Ember transition occurs correctly:
`Transitioned into 'auth'`,

however, PhantomJs does not load:
`[D] ["phantomjs","onLoadFinished","fail"]`

How can this be fixed, why doesn't `visit()` work?

---

Details:

In a project generated using `yo ember`, I have the following test spec:

```
    var assert = chai.assert;
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var should = chai.should();

    App.rootElement = '#main';
    App.setupForTesting();
    App.injectTestHelpers();

    (function () {
        'use strict';

        beforeEach(function() {
            Ember.run(function() {
                App.reset();
            });
            Ember.testing = true;
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            Ember.testing = false;
        });

        describe('Basic', function () {

            describe('Smoke test', function() {
                visit('/auth');

                it('Should contain a header', function() {
                    expect($('.main').length).to.equal(1);
                });
            });
        });
    })();
```

when I run `grunt test --debug`, I get the following output:

```
    [D] ["phantomjs","console","generated -> controller:application [object Object]"]
    generated -> controller:application [object Object]
    [D] ["phantomjs","console","Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember650> [object Object]"]
    Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember650> [object Object]
    [D] ["phantomjs","console","Rendering auth with <App.AuthView:ember664> [object Object]"]
    Rendering auth with <App.AuthView:ember664> [object Object]
    [D] ["phantomjs","console","Transitioned into 'auth'"]
    Transitioned into 'auth'
    [D] ["phantomjs","onLoadFinished","fail"]
    [D] ["phantomjs","fail.load","http://localhost:9001/index.html"]
    ...ERROR
    Warning: PhantomJS unable to load "http://localhost:9001/index.html" URI. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```